# Chaining methods with lazy execution in Python

Tags: python, django, lazy-evaluation, query-builder, method-chaining

I was studying Django when i found they are chaining their query methods like `Post.objects.filter(pk=1).filter(title='first').filter(author='me')` to construct a query without actually executing it, and only execute the query when we try to access and work with its result.

From there i got interested to know how they are doing this so i can apply the same approach in my work, so for instance i can have something like

- Writing code like `myProduct.discount('10%').discountLimit('100$').tax('10$').shipping('20$')`  will only evaluate when i try work with it.
- Build custom DB manager for non Django apps where i can chain my query methods and execute the query automatically only when i try to access its result (or at least when chaining ends). So i can end with something like

  ```
  #doesn't hit the DB
  myPost = Post.objects.select(...).where(...).where(...).limit(...)

  #only hit the DB on usage
  print(myPost.title)
  ```

So my **QUESTION** is, how can i do so?

---

**Approaches that i thought of but i don't like**

- I can implement an .execute() method to perform the actual execution, calling it at the tail of the chain or whenever desired `Post.objects.select(x).where(y).offset(z).execute()`
- I can insert a delay within each of the query builder methods to make sure it is the last in chain

  ```
  class Post:

  def where(self,...):
      me = now()
      self.lastCall = me
      #process the inputs here
      self.query += "WHERE ..."
      self.lazyExecute(me)
      return self

  def lazyExecute(self,identifier):
      delay(5000)
      if self.lastCall = identifier
          self.executeQuery()
      else:
          pass
  ```

Comment: This question is probably too broad but what i can say: there is no way to find out that the chaining ended. You will need a "final" method like `execute()` or `get()`. Another way would be to make your intermediate objects iterable and start the execution when iterated. Having a delay seems like a bad idea. Note that there are already django independent ORMs like SQLAlchemy or pony.orm

Comment: I am more interested in the approach itself rather than its application, since i can apply it on many scenarios.

Having an iterable object seems a good idea when we are having a set of results to work with. but what if the intended result was just a single entry!.

In Django writing something like `Product.objects.get(x)` will still halt the execution of the query till we try to work with it, i.e. `myProduct.price`

Comment: For single results you could implement the fields as descriptors that execute the query when you access them.

Comment: I guess what are you suggesting will do the trick. Feel free to add it as suggested answer.